# Nginx + Socket.io + Nodejs: How to configure socket.io on custom path

Tags: nginx, node.js, socket.io

```
Ubuntu 22.04
Nginx: 1.23.2
Nodejs: 12.22.9
Socket.io: 2.0.3
```

I had a basic Node.js chat room built in Apache2, but I migrated everything over to Ngnix and I'm having problems trying to get the chat room working again. I am trying to get my chat app working as directory `/cnode2/` rather than the root URL (as I have other apps).

When I try loading the page, I am getting this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.*****.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: 
r.doOpen @ websocket.js:112
r.open @ transport.js:80
r.open @ socket.js:245
r @ socket.js:119
r @ socket.js:28
r.open.r.connect @ manager.js:226
r @ manager.js:69
r @ manager.js:37
r @ index.js:60
(anonymous) @ (index):539
cmain.js:160 connect_error: {"type":"TransportError","description":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

It seems like this must be a really simple fix, like maybe it should be connecting to "`wss://www.*****.com/cnode2/socket.io/`" (or maybe not)? I am not quite seeing how to get everything configured correctly or where to configure it. Here are my configs:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodejs app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cluster": "^0.7.7",
    "domain": "0.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "helmet": "^3.12.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "sticky-session": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Ngnix Config:

```
server {
    server_name www.********.com;
    root /home/********/********.com;
    charset utf-8;

    #listen [::]:443 http2 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm-******.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /cnode2/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate ***; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key ***; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Client-side connection to IO - code in the webpage:

```
<script src="https://www.*******.com/cnode2/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('https://www.*********.com/cnode2', {resources: "/cnode2/socket.io", transports: ['websocket','polling']});
</script>
```

Server-side app.js setup:

```
var http = require('http'),
  express = require('express'),
  cluster = require('cluster'),
  net = require('net'),
  io = require('socket.io'),
  io_redis = require('socket.io-redis'),
  sticky = require('sticky-session'),
  os = require('os'),
  helmet = require('helmet'),
  app = new express;
  app.use(helmet());
  var server = http.createServer(app, function(req, res) {
    console.log('launch server');
    res.end('worker: '+cluster.worker.id);
  });

var numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
  console.log('num CPUs: '+numCPUs);

if(!sticky.listen(server, 3000)) {
  for(var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  server.once('listening', function() {
    console.log('server started on 3000 port');
  });
}
else {
  console.log('spawn worker');
  var io = io(server, {path: '/cnode2', transports: ['websocket', 'polling']});
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against the wall and a little bit of trial/error luck, I got everything working by changing the client-side script to:

```
<script>
  var socket = io('https://www.*************.com', {path: "/cnode2", transports: ['websocket','polling']});
</script>
```

It seems that the "path" has to match the "path" set on the server-side app config.